# Move SKSpriteNode by button touch

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, mobile-development

I got SKSpriteNode of hero in my GameScene. I implement two buttons (up and down). I need that SKSpriteNode of my hero is moving up and down by buttons touches. But i only see touchesMoved and touchesEnded methods. I need something about touchesBegan (that feel the button tap while i tap it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create some kind of repeating step that starts at `touchesBegan` and ends at `touchesEnded`, at `touchesCancelled` or when the touch is moved off the node
by checking `touchesMoved`

```
override func touchesBegan(...)
{
   ...
   let moveAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.move(by:CGPoint(x:x,y:y)))
   node.run(moveAction,forKey:"moving")
   ...
}
override func touchesMoved(...)
{
   ...
   //add a check to see if if touch.position is not inside the button
   if (...)
   {
       node.removeAction(withKey:"moving")
   } 
   ...
}
override func touchesEnded(...)
{
   ...
   node.removeAction(withKey:"moving")
   ...
}
override func touchesCancelled(...)
{
   ...
   node.removeAction(withKey:"moving")
   ...
}
```